# What happened when I use persist() in jPA

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I found that I could still operate the entity when I persist it, eg. set the previous Block's id in current Block's priorId, here is the code.

ArticleService.class

```
public void createArticle(Article article, List<Block> blocks) throws Exception {

    ...

    //check blocks
    if (!blocks.isEmpty()) {
        article.setBlocks(blocks);
        articleDAO.create(article);
        //here is the question, after persisting I can still operate it.
        article.setBlocks(BlockUtil.setPriorId(blocks));
    } else {
        throw new Exception("blocks must be set");
    }

    ...

}
```

ArticleDAO.class

```
 public void create(Article article) {
    em.persist(article);
}
```

BlockUtil.class

```
public static List<Block> setPriorId(List<Block> blocks) {

    List<Block> resultBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!blocks.isEmpty()) {
        resultBlocks.add(blocks.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
            blocks.get(i).setPriorId(blocks.get(i - 1).getId());
            resultBlocks.add(blocks.get(i));
        }
    }
    return resultBlocks;
}
```

So I am confused about what happened when I persist an entity. I think it is not saved to the database, right? Maybe it's still managed by EntityManager, but why can I get the id? Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't understand your question.  It is simply an object instance so of course you can access its fields/methods.  What's the problem here?

Comment: What happened when you looked in the JPA providers log to understand it? aka debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityManager remembers all of the entities that are attached to the session (whether you read the entity from the database or persist a new one). Any changes to any of these attached entities are updated into the database at the end of the transaction. Basically, at the end of the transaction (or more specifically, anytime a "flush" occurs"), a "dirty check" is performed on every attached entity. Any "dirty" entities (those that have a different state in the Java runtime than what is stored in the database) result in updates to the database.

Answer (score 1):

In JPA your entity has two states:

- Managed state
- Detached state

When you **persist** entity it goes to **managed** state. For example when you **merge**. The **object in parameter** stay **detached** but **returned object** from **merge** function is **managed**.

Managed state means taht your `EntityManager` keeps the objects in his persistence context. And when you commit the transaction it stores every objects in his context into database. Every changes over managed objects inside transaction will be at the end stored into database.

If you need to store object into database before commit you can do it via `flush` method. But consider all consecvences.

Answer (score 0):

**The Lifecycle of an Entity**

Entity instances are managed by applying operations to the entity using an EntityManager instance,
(`EntityManager em`). Entity instances are in one of four states: new, managed, detached, or
removed:

- New entity instances have no persistent identity and are not yet associated with a persistence context.
- Managed entity instances have a persistent identity and are associated with a persistence context.
- Detached entity instances have a persistent identity and are not currently associated with a persistence context.
- Removed entity instances have a persistent identity, are associated with a persistent context, and are scheduled for removal from the data store.

*Persisting Entities - save to database*

New entity instances become managed and therefore persistent, either by invoking the `persist` method, or by a cascading persist operation, invoked from related entities that have the cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL elements set in the relationship annotation.

*Why cascading entities?*

In relational databases, a foreign key-column in a table refers to a primary key in another database table. If you were to remove the entity (DB record) with the primary '4233455' from the table 'Customers', then the entity in the table CustomerAddress, referring with its foreign key field CustomerId 
(referring to '4233455'), will refer to an entity that no longer exists.

To ensure consistent reference relations in-between tables in your relational database, the notion of table cascading was
defined. It means that the entity’s data is stored to the database when the transaction associated with the persist operation is completed (‘commit’). If the entity is already managed, the persist operation is ignored, although the persist operation will cascade to related entities that have the cascade element
set to PERSIST or ALL in the relationship annotation.

If persist is called on a removed entity instance, the entity becomes managed. 
If the entity is detached, either persist will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, or the transaction commit will fail (which can yield a transaction-rollback, if specified so by your persistence configuration).

*Persistence cache*

Relational databases cache entities in memory. Depending on which relational database is used, the em-operation `em.flush()` can be required to ensure that the data have been saved to disk (or the permanent store of an in-memory database).